# Yii сортировка данных из БД

Tags: php, yii

Не получается отсортировать вытащенные данные.

Код контроллера:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    

    $datas = Transaction::find()->orderBy(['sort_date' => SORT_ASC])->with(['service', 'user'])
                              ->all();
    
    
    return $this->render('index', [
        'datas' => $datas,
    ]);
}
```

Хочу отсортировать данные по столбцу sort_date, но ничего в виде не меняется. Сортируются только по дефолту (по id)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в данном виде:

```
Transaction::find()->orderBy('sort_date ASC')->with(['service', 'user'])->all();
```